# How to perform calculation in string column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, calculation

**df[concentration]**

```
'4.0±0.0'
'2.5±0.2'
'5.8±0.1'
'45.0'
'23'
'26.07'
'64'
```

I want result as:

```
4.00
2.70
5.90
45.00
23.00
26.07
64.00
```

which is (4.0+0.0) taking highest possible value.

However my concentration column is not float then how can I perform calculation on such type of data?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the operations: `±` ? Are all the numbers positive? What have you tried?

Comment: @DaniMesejo There are some normal numbers also and some operations! and yes all are positive numbers!

Comment: Add more examples of the operations

Comment: any reason to downvote the question?

Comment: @wwnde solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split(regex, expand)`, convert outcome digits to float and add row wise using lambda.

Data

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'concentration':['4.0±0.0','2.5±0.2','5.8±0.1','45.0','23','26.07','64']})
```

Solution

```
df['concentration']=df.concentration.str.split('±', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.astype(float)).sum(1)






     concentration
0           4.00
1           2.70
2           5.90
3          45.00
4          23.00
5          26.07
6          64.00
```

Comment: Thanks. But it resulted in this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '=48'

Comment: Should work, what version are you on?. Can you provide full error text or perhaps give a more comprehensive sample dataset?

Comment: It is working for the provided data. I guess there is issue from my end for other type of data also included. Thanks for prompt response. It is working for the posted type of data.

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know what data it is not working well with and will help if I can. Can edit the sample and  let us know